# How to forbid access to a directory via URL without blocking the website to access that directory and use its content

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, directory

I am working in a website that requires blocking access to internauts via URL to  a directory that holds different type of content (images, css files, js files, etc).  This content will be used in the website in certain occasions when it is required and only for a few seconds (advertising), therefore the website will require to access this directory, however the client does not want the content of that directory to be available via URL.

I have tried doing it through htaccess, by validating the user with a password. This forbids internauts entering this directory if they don’t have the password, however this method also block the website when it needs to use some of the content within this directory.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It depends how you access the content. If you reference it on the server side in your code you should have no problems. If you use the full qualified URL you will have a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put an appropriate `.htaccess` file inside of any folder you want to restrict and avoid `mod_rewrite`

```
#
# Restrict access by IP address
#
Order Allow,Deny 
Allow from 127.           # localhost
```

Be sure to confirm your host IP and update accordingly if it's not the default `localhost`

Comment: I tried my host IP and also localhost, but in both cases the images within this directory will not load.

Comment: Can you fetch it server-side with php and echo it to the front-end?

Comment: Yes, it is posible... the problem seems to be the images.